# CakePHP saveAll method

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

On Registration form when i submit form I use:

```
$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'first', 'deep' => true));
```

This row fails. It cannot save my new User and all related data.
I am getting this error:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDBName`.`individuals`, CONSTRAINT`graduate_id_fk`FOREIGN KEY (`education_id`) REFERENCES`educations`(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`.

I guess that CakePHP is trying to save first one of my related with User table records and that is why I get this error.
Does anyone knows how to set the order of saving the objects?
How can I see the generated query ?

Thanks folks.

Comment: Is your table using incrementing IDs?  If so, are they set to correctly increment?

Comment: First of, it is best that you share the array structure of your payload and your db schema. Second, i would normally not set up constraints and rules in the DB when working with Cake. Instead specify them in the model validation rules. Hence having to update rules at only one place.

Answer (score 0):

Output the queries to either the view or a log file:

To output to view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

To output to a log:

```
$db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->showLog();
```

If you are still having problems after seeing the query, post the debug info you collected, along with the array you are passing into `saveAll()`.